# using Boltzman transformation to change PDE to ODE

Tags: transformation, partial-derivative

using Boltzman transformation $\phi=z/\sqrt{t}$ to transform a patrial  Problem:

$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} =\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \left(D{\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}}\right)$$

Prerequisite: 
$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$; and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{z}{t^{3/2}}$

On the left hand side:

$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{z}{t^{3/2}}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}$$

On the right hand side:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \left(D{\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}}\right)=
\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi} \left(D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}     
\right)  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}$$
$$=
\left[
\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi} 
\left(D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}\right)
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}     
+
D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}
\color{red}{\frac{\partial }
{\partial \phi}\left(
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}
\right) }
\right] 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}$$

I think the above-mentioned equations do not have problem. However, There are some issues on solving the red equation $\color{red}{\frac{\partial }
{\partial \phi}\left(
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}
\right) }$:

Method 1: 
$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial }
{\partial \phi}\left(
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}
\right) }=
\frac{\partial }
{\partial z}\left(
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \phi}
\right)=0$$

I am not sure whether this is correct. For example: if we assume $y=x^{2}$, it seems that $\frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial y \partial x}$ has two solutions: (1)$\frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial y }\right)=0$; 
(2)$\frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x }\right)
=\frac{1}{\partial y}\left(2x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$

Method 2:

$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial }
{\partial \phi}\left(
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}
\right) }
\stackrel{\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}{=}
\frac{\partial }
{\partial \phi}\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}
\right)
\stackrel{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}=\frac{\phi}{z}}{=}?$$

I don't know:

(1) What is the problem with the method 1, how to explain the example given?

(2) where method 2 ends up to?

The **RIGHT** solution to Boltzman transformation to original equation is that (the red equation equal 0):

$$-\frac{1}{2}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}=
\left[
\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi} 
\left(D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}\right)\right]
\left(
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}
\right)^{2}
$$
$$-\frac{\phi}{2}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}=
\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi} 
\left(D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}\right)
$$

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Don't replace the outside $ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} $ so fast:

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \left(D{\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}}\right)=
\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \left(D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}     
\right) = \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \left(D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}     
\right) 
$$
So now you see that, you can just pull out the $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} $ through the $ \frac{\partial}{\partial z } $ and then continue
$$
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \left(D\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}
\right)  = \frac{1}{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \left(D \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}  \right)
$$

It's a bit of a trick, I think, because you are NOT making a coordinate transformation. If it were an honest-to-goodness coordinate transformation, lets say replacing $ z,t $ for $ \phi, \psi $, then you would indeed write the $ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} $ of the red line in terms of $ \phi, \psi $ and proceed with differentiating. Rather you are making the ansatz $ \theta(z,t) = f(\frac{z}{\sqrt{t}}) $. Better to understand it this way, I think.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. but I also wish to know how to prove that the red equation equals zero if using method 2. This would shed light on some other problems.